# Wordpress Contact Form 7 Datepicker reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I am having a few issues with the Plugin Contact Form 7, in particular the Datepicker.

On Chrome it works great.

On Firefox and Safari it seems to reload the page when clicking on a date.
Firefox nor Safari supports the needed HTML 5 for the plugin to work so they have created a work around, adding this into the WordPress Functions.php,

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' );
```

This will make the drop down calendar work for Firefox and Safari but when one of the dates is clicked the browser reloads.

I can't really think of away to fix the issue.

If anyone can help with this that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! :D

Been searching and trying to figure this out for a while now.  Finally figured out a simple fix.

Add this to your custom css

```
span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.date-316 {
z-index:99999;}
```

*Just note that the **.date-316** refers to your date field number, you will need to modify that to match your date field, this was the name for mine.*

Hope this helps everyone facing this issue.

Cheers,
Nico